# How to use multiple Schema in hibernate and postgresql

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I'm developing an application with hibernate, Spring boot and postgresql. in my database there is 3 schema ("auth" , "common" , "app") with different tables. and tables in different schema has relation with each other. for example i have two following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS" , schema="auth")
public class User {

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(unique = true , nullable = false)
   private Profile profile;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PROFILES" , schema="common")
public class Profile {

}
```

and here is part of my hibernate configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
   .......

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
       LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

       .........

       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "app");

       ......

       factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
       return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

now my problem is when i try to save a new user using hibernate session factory i get this exception :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "app.users" does not exist
```

so it seems hibernate can't work with multiple schema at the same time. is there any way to solve this problem and make this example work?